# rsync with delete on source and on destination?

Tags: rsync

I understand it is possible to use `--delete` to ensure files deleted in the source are deleted in the destination.

Is there an rsync command, or an alternative to rsync, to mirror deletions that are made on either the source or on the destination? (i.e. Consider a set of html files which may be added/updated/deleted on either server1 or on server2)

---

**PS:** I understand this can lead to conflicts, lets just assume we don't have editors on the source and destination at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You want a bidirectional sync tool. From my understanding rsync is 1-way sync only. There are a few tools to take care of this. You might try something like https://syncthing.net
as it is open source, multi-platform, can handle sync between more than 2 places, and can be run without the involvement of any 3rd party cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm planing to use lsyncd to create a realtime sync between two servers. This tool is normally a one-way service, but if I set it up on both servers pointing to the same folders, it will become a two-way syncing method. Now the only problem is, how to avoid a loop. :)

Comment: Computer scientists have been trying to solve that for years.